# Words order in "the amount of oil produced rose significantly"

Tags: word-order

This is the sentence I’m confused about:

> After eight years, the amount of **oil produced** rose significantly.

Why is it *oil produced* and not *produced oil*?

Comment: "...amount of oil _which had been_ produced..." It's a reduced adjective clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be a mistake if I say "The amount of produced oil rose significantly"?

Comment: It is unidiomatic. It identifies you as an awkward inexperienced speaker of English. Are their situations where it might  be marginally okay? Sure.

Comment: @Xanne...are there

Comment: I think it is a shame this question was moved here. I think it raises interesting issues. I have therefore revived it back on EL&U, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/557160/oil-produced-vs-produced-oil-take-2).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be...

> After eight years, the amount of ***oil produced*** rose significantly.

This is an example of a reduced adjective clause, in other words...

> After eight years, the amount of oil **[*which had been***] produced rose significantly.

If the relative clause applies to the subject (oil) , the relative pronoun (which)  and accompanying form of the verb 'BE' (had been)  can be "reduced", meaning removed.